# Inject script for i18n in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization

I would like to use i18n and i10n in my Angular app. 
If I understood correctly I can inject a script into my `index.html` and the changes regarding the language will change on the fly. I tested it and it works when I added manually the script and refresh the page.

Unfortunately, I am trying to inject the script for the right language on the fly. 
I created a button and I want to add Portuguese language script on the click button.

```
app.controller('appController', ['$scope', '$route', 'UserTopBarWidget', 
                        function($scope, $route, UserTopBarWidgetService){

        $scope.topBarWidget = UserTopBarWidget;
        $scope.topBarWidget.loadTopBarWidget();

    }
}]);
```

In this file I just load the service I created called `UserTopBarWidget`.
The `UserTopBarWidget`:

```
app.service('UserTopBarWidgetService', function($http){
    this.loadTopBarWidget = function(){
    //loading something
};


this.loadPortugueseLanguage = function(){
    var locale = "pt-pt";
    $.getScript("https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/i18n/angular-locale_" + locale + ".js");
}
});
```

I have a page html called `index.html` and inject to it my html files:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../common/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../common/css/style.css" />
    <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div id="container" ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The injected html:

```
<button type="button" id="searchButton" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="topBarWidget.loadPortugueseLanguage()">Portugese</button>

<h2>{{date | date: 'fullDate' }}</h2>
<h2>{{money | currency}}</h2>
```

The answer I get :

```
Tuesday, June 10, 2014
$500.00
```

I would like to see it in Portuguese. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Question

There is no way in pure angular to dynamically change locale so far, you can only do it on bootstrap level but there is a few projects that implement this functionality. This one is particularly good IMHO

https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale

Comment: It's good that somebody mentioned this already. The built-in Angular regional formatting filters are against i18n best practices... Angular Dynamic Locale, to the rescue, but... The problem is, this is in fact a dirty hack. Look into the code if you doubt it. But it is still better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions to your problem really.

One is to use [angular-dynamic-locale](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale) as @maurycy already explained. It's not the cleanest solution I can think of, but it's better than nothing.

The other possible solution is to create your own using other specialized i18n library like [iLib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/i18nlib/) for example.
Why would you ever want to do that?
Well, built-in AngularJS i18n routines does not allow for handling other calendars, time zones and formatting percents. These are serious drawbacks. The fact, that you cannot override a Formatting Locale based on user profile (or you can, but forgot about web site caching) is another.

I recommend using custom iLib-based solution (I used to recommend [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) but after recent changes it seems a bit useless) combined with [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) for User Interface translation and built-in angular-locale for handling plural forms (at the time of writing angular-translate does not handle it particularly well).